# Form #ajax event keyup do not leave me to type

Tags: forms, database, ajax

Using Drupal form with ajax looks good and works fine, but when I change ajax event to keyup it would not let me typing, it will blur the textfield after I type a first letter. Why?
Please anyone came with a solution, the idea is to update the database in real time while typing.
Here is a part of my code:

```
$form['second']['schulbuch_fieldset']['firstname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('firstname'),
    '#value' => $data->firstname,
    '#validate' => array('second_submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'second_callback',
        'event' => 'keyup',
    ),
);

function second_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
    $nid = db_update('student_data')
        ->fields(array(
            'firstname' => $form_state['input']['firstname']
        ))
    ->condition('id', $form_state['build_info']['args'][0])
    ->execute();
    $form_state['rebuild'] = true;
}
function second_callback ($form, &$form_state) {
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#fieldset-schulbuch', drupal_render($form['second']['schulbuch_fieldset']));
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: Create a database connection and perform a write action during typing? It sounds very heavy loading...

Comment: @JimmyKo I do not create a database connection and perform a write action, I update the database on every single letter typed! So will send as many updates as letters, it's does't seem to be the right choice?

Comment: Every time you update the DB record, it indeed make a database connection and write data. It must not a good experience because every key stroke will make the website stop to wait for ajax response.

Comment: You can think of another approach like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4220182/1146907) .

Comment: Ajax is made to work with data without blocking the websites. Yes this is what I want to make, when the input textfield idle for 1 or maybe 5 seconds to send the update to database. Where is the part in code where it's blocking the website? Can I modify it?

Comment: You should not modify it. I need some time to think of it and will get you back after a couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried to work with behaviors or with ajaxSend, ajaxStart, but there I need only to set the idle for a few seconds and then back to php module method (and then how to call the method again to update the database?) only for 1 second idle? Is not a good method.